# Streaming Hikvision IP Camera in Android app

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell me how to access HIK Vision ip camera in Android application? I need to get a live stream from ip camera and then further process this incoming stream.
Thanks

Comment: did u ever find out how to do it? I am having problems @Sri

Comment: Which Hikvision library you used? I am also facing same issue. Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Has anyone found out solution for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

As I know they opened sdk for developer to integrate hikvision camera in android application：https://isgpopen.ezviz.com/developer
I hope this will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).